# Change background color/colour displayed in FVWM

Tags: 11.10, desktop-background

I use FVWM windows manager (and I don't have gnome/unity installed).  The background colour of my window is set by Ubuntu - it is the same colour as the background to the login screen.  Indeed, the FVWM faqs notes that:

> Setting the background image is not really part of the window
>   manager.  If you are using one of the Linux distributions, most
>   likely, some part of the distribution is setting the background for
>   you.

In previous versions (10.04) this background colour was a tasteful brown, but now in 11.10 it is an unbearable blue.  How do I change it please?

Comment: I recommend that you search the http://www.fvwmforums.org/phpBB3/

Answer (score 2):

Okay,  I was using gdm as the login manager.  I switched to lighdm (which, I think is the default in 11.10) and I got a much nicer background theme.

Answer (score 2):

I set the background color in my .fvwm2rc file, as part of the `InitFunction`.  The command I use is

```
AddToFunc InitFunction "I" exec xsetroot -solid SkyBlue
```

(Sorry; I like blue.)